# Loss of focus causes event build-up in Android ActivityGroup

Tags: android

I am making an app which makes use of `ActivityGroup` to embed activities in an `ExpandableListView`, primarily so that 3rd party apps can then extend the functionality of my app by registering additional activities to display as the children of list groups. Unfortunately there is an issue where if more than one group is in the expanded state, and then one of those groups is contracted then expanded again, the activities in the other expanded groups that were visible on the screen then do not receive touch events until after I contract then expand them again, or scroll them out of view then back into view. The events that were attempted then all execute immediately, so for example if a frustrated user tries to click several times on a button that launches a dialog, the result is several dialogs layered upon each other. I think that this issue is something to do with focus. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.